# Convert an image to a cur image

Tags: ruby, image, cursor

I have created a image validation system which checks the magic number of an image and tries to validate the image. Digging up google I got the magic number for cursor images from [here](http://oroboro.com/image-format-magic-bytes/).

```
00 00 01 00 // .ico format
00 00 02 00 // .cur format
```

I have visited many sites which converts images to `.cur` images, however they're converting it to `ico` images not `cur` images :

```
2.2.1 :012 > File.open('~/Pictures/sample/Sora-Meliae-Matrilineare-Mimes-image-x-ico.ico', 'rb').read(9)
 => "\x00\x00\x01\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00" 
2.2.1 :013 > File.open('~/Downloads/test.cur', 'rb').read(9)
 => "\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

The magic number for `ico` images is `\x00\x00\x01\x00` and for `cur` images it's `\x00\x00\x02\x00`.
I have even tried `convert` command to obtain a `cur` image but it also results in an `ico` image:

```
convert sample.cur test.cur
```

So how can I get an authentic `cur` image for testing whose magic no. is `\x00\x00\x02\x00`? For code reference I have written this [blog](http://stealrubyinrails.blogspot.in/2015/07/magic-number-with-ruby.html). Thanks for your help.

Comment: [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/customization/icons/cursors/?order=9)? For example [this one](http://turtlesarealive.deviantart.com/art/Beemo-cursor-312869538) has the correct magic number,

Comment: By the way, check out [`IO.binread`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-binread).

Comment: Thanks @cremno but I still don't understand why when converting an image to `cur` it's ending up as `ico`.